# Enviar sonido en tiempo real con python

Tags: python, socket, audio, stream

estoy intentando realizar un programa (Python) en donde se pueda transmitir el sonido del micrófono de una computadora a otra en tiempo real.

Estuve investigando un poco y lo más cercano que estuve de realizarlo fue con sockets en el que un servidor manda lo que está pasando por el micrófono al cliente, pero hay una latencia en el sonido significante, dejo el código en que me estoy basando por si les sirve.

Me ayudarían mucho si me pudieran decir si voy por el camino correcto o si existen otro tipo de tecnologías que me puedan servir

**Servidor**

```
import pyaudio
import socket
import select

def listarAudios(audio):
    info=audio.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
    numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
    for i in range(0, numdevices):
            if (audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
                print ("Input Device id ", i, " - ", audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))



FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100 #300000
CHUNK =1024 #4096


audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
listarAudios(audio)
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serversocket.bind(('192.168.0.17', 4444))
serversocket.listen(1)


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    for s in read_list[1:]:
        s.send(in_data)
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)


# start Recording
stream = audio.open( format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, stream_callback=callback,input_device_index
=1)
#stream.start_stream()

read_list = [serversocket]
print( "recording...")

try:
    while True:
        readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_list, [], [])
        for s in readable:
            if s is serversocket:
                (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
                read_list.append(clientsocket)
                print( "Connection from", address)
            else:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    read_list.remove(s)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


print("finished recording")

serversocket.close()
# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

**Cliente**

```
import pyaudio
import socket
import sys

from sounddevice import _buffer

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100 #300000
CHUNK = 1024 #4096

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.17', 4444))

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

try:
    while True:
        data = s.recv(CHUNK)
        stream.write(data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

print('Shutting down')
s.close()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

Comment: Siempre habrá latencia

Comment: @Christian Encontré un programa de monitoreo, desconozco qué tecnologías usa pero quiero lograr algo parecido https://stagewave.io/es/ y al ser monitoreo no debe de existir latencia notable

Comment: Para reducir la latencia deberías usar UDP en lugar de TCP. No necesitas establecer una sesión TCP y todo su overhead. Con UDP, cada paquete es una entidad independiente. Si un paquete se pierde, no hay reintentos ni retransmisión; simplemente se descarta.